# java unmarshall LocalDateTime

Tags: java, xml, datetime, jaxb, unmarshalling

This is my adapter class:

```java
public class LocalDateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return new LocalDateTime(v);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(LocalDateTime v) throws Exception {
        return v.toString();
    }

}
```

and this is an object-class where I want to store the date:

```java
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Object {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
    private LocalDateTime time;

    public LocalDateTime getTime() {
            return time;
    }
```

For some reason, I can't compile it. It shows that the problem is at `return new LocalDateTime(v);`. And this is the error I get:

```
Error:(9, 16) java: constructor LocalDateTime in class java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be applied to given types;
      required: java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalTime
      found: java.lang.String
      reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

and the xml part:

```
<time type="dateTime">2000-01-01T19:45:00Z</time>
```

I'm following [this](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html) example.

Comment: This question is old, but I'll ask anyway, for posterity: Are you sure you want to use LocalDateTime?  The reason I ask is that the XML snippet includes a time zone (the "Z", short for Zulu, basically a nickname for GMT) and LocalDateTime does not include time zone information. I wonder: Would it be more appropriate to use ZoneDateTime instead of LocalDateTime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you're using [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) from Java 8. This class has not any constructor for string.

In the example which you're following [`LocalDateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/class-use/LocalDateTime.html) is from [`JodaTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

So, you can do this in to ways:

- Import `org.joda.time.LocalDateTime` (you will need JodaTime dependency) instead of `java.time.LocalDateTime`;
- or change `unmarshal` method to something like this:

  ```
  @Override
  public LocalDateTime unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
      return LocalDateTime.parse(v);
  }
  ```

You may need to inform the [date time format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-), as the default is a format to `2011-12-03T10:15:30`, maybe this:

```
@Override
public LocalDateTime unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
    return LocalDateTime.parse(v, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT);
}
```

Also, in `java.time.LocalDateTime` [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString--) will output one of the following ISO-8601 formats:

- uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm
- uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
- uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS
- uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS
- uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS

Comment: I wonder, if I use `return LocalDateTime.parse(v.substring(0,v.length-1));`, it works as well.. what's the difference then?

Comment: You can, ensuring the same pattern in both `marshal` and `unmarshal` is ok.

Comment: btw, it works with `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME` but not with `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`. How come?

Comment: Maybe 'cause input format. In DateTimeFormatter you can see formats for this constants.